# My computer connects to the more distant of my 2 routers by default

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I'm running two routers in my home because one isn't enough to get signal from one side of my apartment to the other. So I have the main NetGear dual-band router in my living room connected to my modem, and I have ethernet running to a second Belkin router across the apartment in my bedroom. They are both running the same SSID and security setup, so when I walk across my apartment, the signal on my phone goes from strong in my living room, to weaker in the middle, to strong again near the bedroom. This gives me confidence that I've set this up correctly.

The problem is that my personal computer, running Windows 7 Home Premium (64-bit), which is in the living room area, always wants to connect to the router on the other side of the apartment. I get 2 bars of signal indication (expected for the distance to the other router), but when I disconnect, the network changes to 5 bars (expected for the living room router). When I reconnect it's fine for a while, but after a short time my signal goes down again as if it's connected to the far router until I repeat this process.

This kind of network troubleshooting is outside of my knowledge domain, so I really don't know how to further investigate this issue, so I'm wondering if anyone can recommend settings to check, steps to try, or additional information I can provide to get a resolution to this.

Comment: Which OS are you operating on?

Comment: Windows 7 Home Premium; added to the info in the question.

Comment: Must be a big apartment.

Comment: Check [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/How-do-I-prevent-my-computer-from-switching-between-two-preferred-networks) out. And i doubt you will be moving this computer around your home, so maybe just delete that network from known networks.

Comment: @Kitet It might as well be a laptop (unless I missed something in the Q) which he moves around a lot. I do move mine...

Comment: The way I've set it up is to attempt to have only one network, using the second router as just a range extension. So both routers are broadcasting the same SSID on the same channel with the same security. The ethernet from the main router feeds into a device port of the secondary router (as opposed to the main internet port), so there should not be two networks in my home. So I'm baffled why this should even be an issue...

Comment: What are the radio capabilities of the two routers? Are they both dual-band? What channels are they on? Do they both use 3 spatial streams in both channels? Which router was your Windows 7 PC connected to when you put it to sleep? It could be that your PC is connecting to the last AP used, or the one with faster 802.11n capabilities (more spatial streams), or the one on a channel it can more easily scan. Some channels are radar/DFS channels that have to be scanned passively = slowly.

Comment: Have the same problem happening with Linux